# Is it possible to use 2 objects feed in single VF Page

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed-tracking, chatter-feed

I'm trying to use 2 objects __Feed in single VF Page, but i'm unable to get the result. I'm able to view the one object chatter functionality and another object showing the record information but it was disabled the chatter functionality.
Can anyone please help on this issue

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

My first idea would be that the feed-mechanism might not be designed to occur multiple times on a single page. So I would see, if there is a JavaScript error. Look into your console (press F12) and search for errors. I prefer Firebug for such things.

If the two feeds for whatever reason does not work simultaneously, you could use two separate vf-pages internally combining them on a third vf-page using Iframes. This must work.

From a UI standpoint my suggestion is ridiculous and Iframes will come with their own downsides, but as a last resort a sure solution to get what you want - but only if all other options fail.